# html 3 column layout

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a layout that has a 3 column [fluid][fixed][fluid] layout where [fixed] is centered in the middle of the page.

I've been looking around for a while now and cant seem to come up with a solution that doesn't require tables. Does anyone have a solution that only uses div's and css?

Comment: is the fixed center column supposed to be centered? (some more details of what you've tried or are trying to do would help)

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

http://www.css-lab.com/demos/3col-fluid/3col-fix-cntr.html

Just right click and view source to see how it's done.